# Making video in banner

Tags: css, html

So on my website here
http://umbrellacorperation.com/

What im trying to do?

- I am trying to get the video to play in the banner and resize the Iframe to whatever resolution people are using on their devices
- Trying to make sure that it autoplay
- Make the logo, text, & button be in front of the video (obviously not working

Sadly i dont know much about html5 and this is as fast as it goes basically.

Here is the section of the code that is made already but im sure that im doing it wrong in many ways

```
<div id="banner">
  <iframe width="600" height="1000" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BkEQZc1RH5M?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div class="container">
<div class="title">
            <h2>Welcome to Umbrella Corperation</h2>
              <span class="byline">Come join our Wonderful Community</span></div>
            <ul class="actions">
              <img src="images/apilogo3.png" width="300" height="300" alt=""/>
              <li><a href="http://umbrellacorperation.com/forum/" class="button">Click here for Forum Access</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would appreciate it so much if someone can help me get this to work!

Comment: read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 0):

Use this code as reference for videoplay:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HTML5 Video Player</title>
<style>
    body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            border: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
    }
    header {
            text-align: center;
    }
    #player {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 4px;
    }
    #player > div {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>HTML5 Video Player</h1>
</header>
<section id="player">
    <div>
        <video src="yourvideo.mp4"
            controls
            width="720" height="480">
            Your browser does not support the video element, please #D try <a href="yourvideo.mp4">downloading the video instead</a>
            </video>
        </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Modify CSS as your need.